# What is causing the packet loss in my network setup?

Tags: networking, switch, packet-loss

I have a [network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC0rA.png) consisting of a Wifi router (ASUS RT-AC68U) connected to a switch (Netgear GS116) that connects to multiple network devices (PC, Laptop, NAS).

Connections over the switch experience a packet loss of about 10%, for both PC to PC or PC to internet. Removing the switch from the network, i.e. connecting the network devices directly to the router removes any packet loss. I need the switch to connect all my devices to the network - the router has only four Ethernet ports.

Because I thought the switch has a hardware fault, I replaced it already under warranty. However, with the replaced, new device I get exactly the same issue. What are possible causes of the packet loss in my setup and how can I fix them?

Comment: Change brand. The price for a 16 port Cisco SG110 or SG200 is not too far from Netgear. Or choose a professional line.

Comment: That's an unnecessary suggestion. Netgear hardware can handle tasks like moving packets without dropping them just fine.